# What is the difference between deque( [1,2,3] ) and deque.append( [1,2,3] )?

Tags: python, queue, deque

I have noticed that the following incurs an iterable error.

```
q = deque([1,2,3])
x, y, z = q.popleft()
# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

But the code below works which I thought the same operation:

```
q = deque()
deque.append([1,2,3])
x, y, z = q.popleft()
```

What is the difference between the two ways above?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q.popleft()` returns the first element of the deque. In the first case it is `int` and in the second it is a list of ints. You should write in the first case: `x, y, z = q`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment. 
However, what makes them different since I initialize the queue in the same way?

Comment: @TreyYi When you write ```q = deque()``` it is the same if you would write  ```q = deque([])```. You initialize it with an empty array. When you call ```q.append([1,2,3])``` it is the same if you would write ```q = deque([[1, 2, 3]])```. So ```[1, 2, 3]``` here is not the deque itself but the first element of the deque. That's the difference